# Create master public key after HMAC-SHA512

Tags: hash, public-key, mastering-bitcoin

I have that result after hash_pbkdf2

```
5B56C417303FAA3FCBA7E57400E120A0CA83EC5A4FC9FFBA757FBE63FBD77A89A1A3BE4C67196F57C39A88B76373733891BFABA16ED27A813CEED498804C0570
```

[image]

left 256 bits are:

```
5B56C417303FAA3FCBA7E57400E120A0CA83EC5A4FC9FFBA757FBE63FBD77A89
```

in base 10 are

```
m = 41313771436092106966070828753784402438291933698697412643075684398900444625545
```

right 256 bits are

```
A1A3BE4C67196F57C39A88B76373733891BFABA16ED27A813CEED498804C0570
```

in base 10 are

```
G = 73111678085084231450767103284505018606851115862905010375565411946552667932016
```

To calculate Master Public Key I have to do

```
m*G

bc <<< “73111678085084231450767103284505018606851115862905010375565411946552667932016 * 41313771436092106966070828753784402438291933698697412643075684398900444625545”
```

result

```
3020519157716314193817478999423070077945694756523017007189820738431399197829981163447928137705627795431573290757393848092663806903883822516032876636948720
```

that result is not correct

Comment: See https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/84116/get-master-private-key-from-bip39-seed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> m*G
>
> bc <<<
>   “73111678085084231450767103284505018606851115862905010375565411946552667932016
>   * 41313771436092106966070828753784402438291933698697412643075684398900444625545”

Careful, G is a secp256k1 elliptic curve generator point. You cannot multiply it as you would a scalar. You need a secp256k1 library to perform scalar x EC-Point operations.

Comment: I suggest you try a command line tool, such as Libbitcoin-BX for EC-point operations in command line: https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki/bx-ec-to-public

Comment: thanks james, I'd like to do without library if possible

Comment: that library is very powerful, with `bx ec-to-public 5B56C417303FAA3FCBA7E57400E120A0CA83EC5A4FC9FFBA757FBE63FBD77A89` I can find Public Key compressed, But i'd like to use even `A1A3BE4C67196F57C39A88B76373733891BFABA16ED27A813CEED498804C0570` and understand how it works

Comment: Have a look at the operations necessary for scalar x EC point operation, it's pretty complex with just basic CL tools: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve

Comment: Yep you are right :)
Thanks again James for your time