# Get Master Private Key from BIP39 Seed

Tags: wallet, private-key, public-key, bip32-hd-wallets

I have BIP39 Seed:

```
5b56c417303faa3fcba7e57400e120a0ca83ec5a4fc9ffba757fbe63fbd77a89a1a3be4c67196f57c39a88b76373733891bfaba16ed27a813ceed498804c0570
```

I want to get Master private Key

Then I Have to use HMAC-SHA512, I can use this [site](https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html), which secret I have to add ? I don't have any secret, for test  I choose "mnemonic", the same constant that I use to generate BIP39seed (is it correct? )

the result is:

> 9744d0d7e168f725b6cc36a73c24dfc91bd6d80bf5a6871ad2c6c0b854e4e281b74049c41d25f0b338b3fc9b053b87b95636c3c94c31f37458fe98a09a4a94c9

and I can get

```
left 256 bits  => 9744d0d7e168f725b6cc36a73c24dfc91bd6d80bf5a6871ad2c6c0b854e4e281
right 256 bits  => b74049c41d25f0b338b3fc9b053b87b95636c3c94c31f37458fe98a09a4a94c9
```

And I can Get master private key in this way?

```
PKM = bx ec-to-wif 9744d0d7e168f725b6cc36a73c24dfc91bd6d80bf5a6871ad2c6c0b854e4e281
```

> result:
>   L2Hku6wzwvWnHAct8TmtfvviE4QXBTXtZrae2buXwjq5mRG4doF2

but this result is not in https://iancoleman.io/bip39/ If I import my mnemonic phrase

> (army van defense carry jealous true garbage claim echo media make crunch)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the mechanics for "Mastering Bitcoin" [**Creating an HD Wallet from the Seed**](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch05.asciidoc#creating-an-hd-wallet-from-the-seed) using  [**bitcoin-explorer**](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki/bx-mnemonic-to-seed) and this Python [**HMAC**](https://pypi.org/project/hmac_cli/) command.

**Root Seed:**

`% echo "army van defense carry jealous true garbage claim echo media make crunch" | bx mnemonic-to-seed -p ""`

**`5b56c417303faa3fcba7e57400e120a0ca83ec5a4fc9ffba757fbe63fbd77a89a1a3be4c67196f57c39a88b76373733891bfaba16ed27a813ceed498804c0570`**

**Master Private Key:**

`% echo 5b56c417303faa3fcba7e57400e120a0ca83ec5a4fc9ffba757fbe63fbd77a89a1a3be4c67196f57c39a88b76373733891bfaba16ed27a813ceed498804c0570 | bx base16-decode | hmac --algorithm sha512 --key "Bitcoin seed" - | cut -c 1-64`

**`b2a0d576b828b537688b561f2cfa8dac3602d54c62bde619ad5331e6c235ee26`**

**Master Public Key:**

`% echo 5b56c417303faa3fcba7e57400e120a0ca83ec5a4fc9ffba757fbe63fbd77a89a1a3be4c67196f57c39a88b76373733891bfaba16ed27a813ceed498804c0570 | bx base16-decode | hmac --algorithm sha512 --key "Bitcoin seed" - | cut -c 1-64 | bx ec-to-public`

**`03ca72b45eede592f059b7eaf3da13eb7d8d15aa472b6f79f74820bb22ff596186`**

**Chain Code:**

`% echo 5b56c417303faa3fcba7e57400e120a0ca83ec5a4fc9ffba757fbe63fbd77a89a1a3be4c67196f57c39a88b76373733891bfaba16ed27a813ceed498804c0570 | bx base16-decode | hmac --algorithm sha512 --key "Bitcoin seed" - | cut -c 65-128`

**`b70d675323c40ec461e0a6af603b1f135fb2af9ae753eeff18922732a73b0f05`**

Comment: Can I  add two secp256k1 keys together with bx ?

Comment: For cyclic ordinate “Normalization”, you will want to examine **bx** [**ec-add-secrets**](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki/bx-ec-add-secrets) and [**ec-multiply-secrets**](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer/wiki/bx-ec-multiply-secrets)

Comment: What is the use of a master public key? Can I see all the the public addresses derived from that HD wallet?

Comment: Instead of all of that decoding, hashing and cutting you can just use the `bx hd-*` commands :). `hd-new`, `hd-private`, `hd-public`, `hd-to-address`, `hd-to-ec`, `hd-to-public`, `hd-to-wif`.

Answer (score 2):

> which secret I have to add ? I don't have any secret, for test I choose "mnemonic", the same constant that I use to generate BIP39seed (is it correct? )

No, that is incorrect. You use the key `mnemonic` when converting the BIP 39 mnemonic to a seed. You already have the seed, so you don't use the key `mnemonic`. You should instead be following the steps described in [BIP 32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki#Master_key_generation).

So you need to use HMAC-SHA512 with the key `Bitcoin seed`. Furthermore, the site that you used hashes the input as a string, not as the bytes represented by the hex values. This will result in the wrong hash. You need to use a different site. I used https://cryptii.com/pipes/hmac and converted the key `Bitcoin seed` to it's hex representation using https://www.asciitohex.com/. Setting the input to be hexadecimal bytes and setting the key to be the hex form of `Bitcoin seed` results in the hash:

```
b2a0d576b828b537688b561f2cfa8dac3602d54c62bde619ad5331e6c235ee26b70d675323c40ec461e0a6af603b1f135fb2af9ae753eeff18922732a73b0f05
```

If we look at the master private key we get from your mnemonic (listed as BIP 32 root key on https://iancoleman.io/bip39/), we see that its private key and chaincode are the same as the above hash.